# How to list all unique contracts on the network?

Tags: horizon, smart-contract

From [a study comparing smart contracts on Ethereum and Stellar](https://globalcoinreport.com/stellar-xlm-casting-a-shadow-over-ethereums-smart-contract-operations/), there's a point in the study about downloading all contracts:

> Testing Smart Contracts: Ethereum vs. Stellar
>
> **The researchers from the National University of Singapore and UCL then
>   decided to download all live smart contracts that actively existed on
>   Ethereum’s platform at the moment of testing.** There were nearly a
>   million of active live smart contracts and as they started with their
>   testing, they have discovered that more than 34000 smart contracts
>   showed vulnerability with over 2000 smart contracts showing high-risk
>   vulnerability, which meant that these contracts could be manipulated
>   “easily” by a third party that would in majority of cases represent
>   hackers who want to take advantage of unintended issues in ETH smart
>   contracts.
>
> For further testing, the team has gone on by choosing 3759 different
>   smart contracts so they would be able to check the results again. And,
>   the results were devastating as the team was able to find major
>   vulnerabilities and flaws within only 10 seconds of testing for
>   positivity.

(Emphasis mine.)

What is the operation that would list /all/ unique smart contracts active on stellar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stellar smart contracts are basically transactions that succeed or fail based on various constraits (most simple example: a pre defined transaction that makes a payment only if published in a specific time frame). Unlike Ethereum they are not published/distributed on chain in advance, so there is no way to figure that out.